# How to fix a content editing batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have over one hundred txt files, and in each file are words which need to be changed.

If anyone can help me fix this I would appreciate it.

Here is my script:

```bash
@echo off

set "Find=Earth"
set "Replace=World"

set "source=Folder1"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%source%\*.txt"') do (
      set "line=%%b"
      if defined line set "line=!line:%Find%=%Replace%!"
      echo(!line!
   )
) > %source%\%%~nxa.txt.bak
```

I was trying with a test file to find the word `Earth` and replace it with another word, or delete it completely.

`document 1.txt`

```
Earth
```

`%~nxa.txt.bak`

```
1. World
```

Somehow, I get a number and the output I get `%~nxa.txt.bak`

I did take a look around the site, and I did find a script that changes data, but it took too long to do so.

Comment: `if defined line set "line=!line:%Find%=%Replaced%!"` Um- you're establishing `replace`, `not `replaceD` and your ouput file is source%\%%~nx**a**.txt.bak where `%%a` is the line number, but actually - your code is the wrong approach...

Comment: Oh Ok, I corrected the D so what would be the right approach, I did find a script that uses TYPE but man it took forever, it was way to slow for editing I'm looking for simple with batch scripting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %%e in ("%source%\*.txt") do (
 for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%%e"') do (
  set "line=%%b"
  if defined line set "line=!line:%Find%=%Replace%!"
  echo(!line!
 )
) > %source%\%%~nxe.txt.bak
```

should cure your problem - `%%e` contains the filename, `%%a` the line number within the file `%%e` and `%%b` the line contents.

Comment: I updated the question to fix a script since that was the issue